# How to return properly using async in this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, morgan

So i have this code

```
const log = require("./queries/logQuery");
const moment = require('moment');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const custom = async (tokens, req, res) => {
    if(req.session){
        if(req.session.superadmin){
            const date = moment().locale('id').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            const usr = req.session.superadmin;
            const method = tokens.method(req, res);
            const endpoint = tokens.url(req, res);
            const statusCode = tokens.status(req, res);

            await log.addLog(date, usr, method, endpoint, statusCode)
        }else if(req.session.user){
            const date = moment().locale('id').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            const usr = req.session.user;
            const method = tokens.method(req, res);
            const endpoint = tokens.url(req, res);
            const statusCode = tokens.status(req, res);
    
            await log.addLog(date, usr, method, endpoint, statusCode)
        }
        return [
            tokens.method(req, res),
            tokens.url(req, res),
            tokens.status(req, res),
            tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
            tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
        ].join(' ')
    }
}

router.use(morgan(custom))
```

I'm trying to use async in the morgan logger, however the return always gave me "[object Promise]", i've tried setting each of the return using await but to no avail, how to fix this?

Comment: What is `log.addLog()` and why do you have to `await` it?  Also, this code could be DRYed up a bit as you have duplicated code in branches of the `if/else`.

Comment: Greetings @jfriend00 it refers to a function in a separate file which is used for storing the data into the database, the code are this: `const addLog = async (date, usr, method, endpoint, statusCode) => {
    const add = await pool.query(INSERT INTO public.log(date, usr, method, endpoint, status_code) VALUES ('${date}', '${usr}', '${method}', '${endpoint}', '${statusCode}'))
    return add;
}`

Comment: So, why do you need `await log.addLog()`? Why can't use just use `log.adLog().catch(...)`?  If you can switch to that, then you can remove the `async` from the `custom` function and it will then work properly with `morgan()`.

Comment: I see, thanks will definitely try it. I was wondering if i could use async with morgan logger, but as you said it does not support an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confusing question.  `custom` is an `async` function thus is ALWAYS returns a promise.  That's how ALL `async` functions work.

But, it looks like morgan wants the callback you pass it to synchronously return that array.  You can't do what you're trying to do the way you're trying to do it as the morgan API does not support using an `async` callback.

One way to solve this problem would be to remove the `await` on `await log.addLog(...)` so you can then remove the `async` on the `custom` function:

```
const custom = (tokens, req, res) => {
    if(req.session){
        if(req.session.superadmin){
            const date = moment().locale('id').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            const usr = req.session.superadmin;
            const method = tokens.method(req, res);
            const endpoint = tokens.url(req, res);
            const statusCode = tokens.status(req, res);

            log.addLog(date, usr, method, endpoint, statusCode).catch(err => console.error);
        }else if(req.session.user){
            const date = moment().locale('id').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            const usr = req.session.user;
            const method = tokens.method(req, res);
            const endpoint = tokens.url(req, res);
            const statusCode = tokens.status(req, res);
    
            log.addLog(date, usr, method, endpoint, statusCode).catch(err => console.error);
        }
        return [
            tokens.method(req, res),
            tokens.url(req, res),
            tokens.status(req, res),
            tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
            tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
        ].join(' ')
    }
}
```

Comment: @ipeenkdownloader - I added a possible solution to my answer.